# Applying squeeze/sandwich theorem to find $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_\limits{k=n}^{5n} k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl( \frac{n}{n^2}+\frac{n+1}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{5n}{n^2}\Bigr)$$

I know how to directly compute it, but I am required to use squeeze theorem.

Let $S_n$ be the sequence concerned.
I tried $(4n+1)\frac{n}{n^2}<S_n<(4n+1)\frac{5n}{n^2}$, but it gives me $4<\lim S_n<20$. What should I do to get appropriate bounds so that squeeze theorem can be applied?

Comment: To apply queeze theorem you may use $S_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\big(\frac{5n\cdot (5n+1)}{2}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\big)$

Comment: I feel like, from the direct formula of $S_n$, you can apply squeeze theorem to get the answer?

Comment: @durianice Does your teacher force you to use the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @Alexdanut Yes, the problem explicitly states that the squeeze theorem must be used.

Comment: @0-thUser Can you provide more details? I still struggle on how to apply the squeeze theorem on the formula you gave out.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the sum $A_n=\sum^{5n}_{k=n}k$ and the area of the trapezoidal $P_n$ made of by the positive side of the $x$-axis, the identity line $y=x$, and the vertical line $x=n$ and $x=5n$

splitting the  segment $[n,5n]$ in $4n$ pieces of length $1$.

1. For each $n\leq k < 5n$,  we can construct the rectangles with base $[k,k+1]$, and height $k+1$. The sums of the areas of such rectangles is
   $\sum^{5n}_{k=n+1}k$ is larger than the are of the $P_n$, which is $4n\frac{n+4n}{2}=12n^2$. This gives
   $$ 12n^2 < A_n$$
2. Similarly, for each $n\leq k < 5n$,  we can construct the rectangles with base $[k,k+1]$, and height $k$. The sums of the areas of such rectangles is
   $\sum^{5n-1}_{k=n}k$ is smaller than the are of the $P_n$, which is $\frac{4n(n+4n)}{2}=12n^2$. This gives
   $$ A_n-(5n-1)<12n^2$$

Putting things together

$$ 12 <\frac{1}{n^2}A_n <12 +\frac{5n-1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl( \frac{n}{n^2}+\frac{n+1}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{5n}{n^2}\Bigr)$$

Note that the average of $n$ and $5n$ is $3n$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty;h\to 0^+}\Bigl( \frac{3n-h}{n^2}+\frac{3n-h}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{3n-h}{n^2}\Bigr) < S < \lim_{n\to\infty;h\to0^+}\Bigl( \frac{3n+h}{n^2}+\frac{3n+h}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{3n+h}{n^2}\Bigr)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty;h\to 0^+} 12-\frac{4h}{n} < S < \lim_{n\to\infty;h\to 0^+}12+\frac{4h}{n}$$

$$\implies \boxed{S=12}$$

Also note that a tight bound like this is required to evaluate the sum using squeeze theorem.

Comment: Seems to me an implicit way of using $\sum_{k=n}^{5n}k=3n(4n+1)$

Comment: Well the bounds with $n$ and $5n$ aren't tight enough. So I thought this could be it.

Comment: In fact, I don't think this limit can be evaluated without using that formula. But once we have to use that formula, there is no need to use squeeze theorem anymore.

Comment: Exactly! I think the original question would not have asked to evaluate it using squeeze theorem at all

Comment: @enzotib: comparing the sum with the area of some trapezoid will give geometrical bounds to use the squeeze the. Then again, I agree that the limit in this instance is easy to get by direct methods.